# Is there a blend mode for drawing "visible" lines?

Tags: opengl

I'm making a paint-like program. I want to allow users to draw rectangles (selections). Presently, I'm painting the rectangle using white lines. However, if they try drawing one over top a white image, the line won't be visible.

Other programs get around this by using "marching ants" or by using a sort of inverted color so that the line is always visible.

What's the easiest way to achieve this effect in OpenGL?

If relevant, I'm using C# w/ OpenTK + WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL can do this, too. Look at the various logic operations offered by OpenGL. Using the XOR logic operation, you'll get a nicely contrasting line.

[OpenGL glLogicOp reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLogicOp.xml)

Comment: That's sweet. That's more or less exactly what I was looking, but unfortunately it looks pretty bad with anti-aliasing enabled. The edges of my lines are hard and jagged with it enabled.

Comment: With XOR: http://i.imgur.com/ScpfKB0.png Without: http://i.imgur.com/QM6gJpN.png No way around that is there?

Comment: @Mark: Well, Antialiasing doesn't really play well with logic ops, as logic ops work on the whole pixel, whereas antialiasing breaks down the pixel in several samples. Way around this with logic ops? Unfortunately none. I suggest you copy your to-be-selected-from image into a texture (use a FBO), draw the lines into another texture (use a FBO) and combine them using a shader.

Comment: Bummer. I'll have to look into that more later. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could draw two rectangles, with colors opposite each other, offset by one pixel from each other.  Or you could just use the color they're drawing with (WYSIWYG-style).  Drawing a white rectangle atop a white image won't change the image, so why should feedback suggest that it does?

Comment: Because I'm not really "painting" a white rectangle, it's a selection tool ;) The offset trick might be an easy fix though. Not quite as pretty as I was hoping, but workable.